# Does jOOQ support parsing of nested rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

I am evaluating if we can migrate from plain JDBC to jOOQ for our project. Most of it looks promising, but I am wondering currently about one specific flow: nested rows. Let me explain.

Say you have the following two tables:

```
class(id, name)
student(id, name, class_id)
```

(We assume that a student can only be part of one class.)

Let's create a *response type* for these tables. I will be using these in the queries below.

```
create type type_student as(id integer, name text);
create type type_class as(id integer, name text, students type_student[]);
```

Now let's fetch all classes with its student by using nested rows:

```
select row(class.id, class.name, array
       (
         select row(student.id, student.name)::type_student
         from   student
         where  student.class_id = class.id
       ))::type_class
from   class
```

A useful variant is to use only nested rows in arrays:

```
select class.id, class.name, array
       (
         select row(student.id, student.name)::type_student
         from   student
         where  student.class_id = class.id
       ) as students
from   class
```

I am wondering if jOOQ has an elegant approach to parse such results containing nested rows?

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing"? Are you talking about the jOOQ parser (e.g. exposed through this website here: https://www.jooq.org/translate), which parses your SQL string into the jOOQ expression tree, or are you using this term colloquially to say "jOOQ supports the feature"?

Comment: Hi @LukasEder. My wording was indeed not very clear. I meant asking whether jOOQ supports to parse such results to POJO models in _an elegant fashion_. From experience with JDBC, I learned the hard way that parsing `row(...)` results and especially nested `row(...)` results is quite cumbersome and frustrating. I am wondering which functionality jOOQ provides to parse these. So regarding your question, I am asking for the latter. I hope this made some sense. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I see, "parse" as in "parse the tedious PostgreSQL object notation" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of the word "parse" could mean several things, and I'll answer them all in case anyone finds this question looking for "jOOQ" / "parse" / "row".

#### Does the `org.jooq.Parser` support row value expressions?

Not yet (as of jOOQ 3.10 and 3.11). jOOQ ships with a SQL parser that parses (almost) anything that can be represented using the jOOQ API. This has various benefits, including:

- Being able to reverse engineer DDL scripts for the code generator
- Translating SQL between dialects (see an online version here: https://www.jooq.org/translate)

Unfortunately, it cannot parse row value expressions in the projection yet i.e. in the `SELECT` clause.

#### Does the jOOQ API support ("parse") row value expressions?

Yes, you can use them using the various [`DSL.row()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-org.jooq.Field...-) constructors, mainly for predicates, but also for projections by wrapping them in a `Field` using [`DSL.rowField()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#rowField-org.jooq.Row2-). As of jOOQ 3.11, this is still a bit experimental as there are many edge cases in PostgreSQL itself, related to what is allowed and what isn't. But in principle, queries like yours should be possible

#### Does jOOQ support parsing the serialised version of a PostgreSQL `record`

PostgreSQL supports these anonymous `record` types, as well as named "composite" types. And arrays thereof. And nesting of arrays and composite types. jOOQ can serialise and deserialise these types if type information is available to jOOQ, i.e. if you're using the code generator. For instance, if your query is stored as a view

```sql
create view test as
select row(class.id, class.name, array
       (
         select row(student.id, student.name)::type_student
         from   student
         where  student.class_id = class.id
       ))::type_class
from   class
```

Then, the code generator will produce the appropriate types, including:

- `TypeStudentRecord`
- `TypeClassRecord`

Which can be serialised as expected. In principle, this would be possible also without the code generator, but you'd have to create the above types yourself, manually, so why not just use the code generator.

Comment: My apoligies for the late response. Thank you, very useful insights.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/nested-selects/

```
Field<Object> records =
create.select(student.id, student.name)
      .from(student)
      .where(student.class_id.eq(class.id)
      .asField("students");

create.select(class.id, class.name, array, records)
      .from(class)
      .fetch();
```

The above example might not work directly as I have not tried, but just wanted to give a general idea.

Note: that the object records is not executed alone. When `fetch` is called in the second statement, JOOQ should create one SQL statement internally.

Comment: Thank you. Although this does not really answer my question (see my comment above), I really appreciate the effort and explanation. This does not make use of `row(...)` construction of the student records though.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.0/org/jooq/DSLContext.html

There is a command called selectFrom(TABLE_NAME) which replaces select(student.id, student.name) to return the whole row